# TiKZ: place shortened arrow between every pair of points in a draw statement?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, tikz-arrows

What is the simplest and most direct way of creating a sequence of arrows, like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,1) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

so that the line between every pair of points is an arrow, which leaves a gap at each end?  So that, for example

```
\draw (2,1) -- (1,1);
```

actually draws

```
\draw[->] (1.9,1) -- (1.1,1);
```

I've tried:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->,shorten >=1mm,shorten <=1mm] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,1) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which I imagine should work, but in fact just draws the line connecting all the points.

I could probably do some sort of `foreach` command, like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x/\y in %
  {{(0,0)/(1,0)},{(1,0)/(2,0)},{(2,0)/(2,1)},{(2,1)/(1,1)},{(1,1)/(0,1)},{(0,1)/(0,0)}}
  \draw[->,shorten >=1mm,shorten <=1mm] \x -- \y;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but this again seems a bit clumsy what with all the repetition of coordinates.   Is there a better way?

**STOP PRESS**

This works, is simple, doesn't use any fancy macros, and more to the point comports with my programming style:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x  [remember=\x as \lastx (initially {(0,0)})] in %
  {(1,0),(2,0),(2,1),(1,1),(0,1),(0,0)} 
  {
   \draw[->,shorten >=1mm,shorten <=1mm] \lastx -- \x;
   \filldraw[fill=black] \x circle(0.05);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You can use `to` paths instead with a custom style

Comment: you can see here http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/arrows/

Comment: I worked it out with foreach and remember! See above.

Comment: @Alasdair I think it would be better if you write a proper answer instead of adding the solution to your question (you can, of course, accept your own answer if no better option appears).

Answer (score 3):

A decoration could do it:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{multiple arrows}{draw}{
  \state{draw}[width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength]{
    \draw [multiple arrows path/.try] (0,0) -- (\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength,0);
  }
}
\tikzset{multiple arrows/.style={multiple arrows path/.style={#1},
  decoration=multiple arrows, decorate}}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [multiple arrows={shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm, -stealth}] 
  (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,1) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it, learning about the `remember` option of `foreach`, which allows, in effect, iteration over consecutive pairs of objects:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x  [remember=\x as \lastx (initially {(0,0)})] in %
   {(1,0),(2,0),(2,1),(1,1),(0,1),(0,0)} 
     {
       \draw[->,shorten >=1mm,shorten <=1mm] \lastx -- \x;
       \filldraw[fill=black] \x circle(0.05);
     }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This works very well, and seems conceptually straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using a new command `\myarrows`.
This command turns `(...) -- (...) -- ...` into a series of `\draw (...) -- (...);`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\myarrows#1;{\myarrowsaux#1--;}
\def\myarrowsaux#1--#2--#3;{%
  \draw[->, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt] #1--#2;
  \def\myarrowstemp{#3}%
  \ifx\myarrowstemp\empty\else
    \myarrowsaux #2--#3;
  \fi}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \myarrows (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,1) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why use you  cycle. It does nothing for me.

Comment: @touhami Thank you for pointing out. I corrected my answer.